Linking multiple local projects via UI5 Tooling workspace fails
My VS Code workspace looks something like this:
SAPUI5
 -zkdklsel (Component. Neither an application nor a library)
 -zkdtagesdok (Application)

In the zkdtagesdok app descriptor, I defined the usage of the zkdklsel component:
"componentUsages": {
  "klientSelect": {
    "name": "zkdklsel",
    "settings": {},
    "...": "..."

When I preview in VS Code, I always get the error:

ModuleError: failed to load 'zkdklsel/Component.js' from ../resources/zkdklsel/Component.js: script load error

I created a ui5-workspace.yaml in zkdtagesdok - same place where the ui5.yaml is:
specVersion: "workspace/1.0"
metadata:
    name: default
dependencyManagement:
    resolutions:
        - path: ../zkdklsel

I assume it is processed, because if I set something like workspace/8.0 which does not exist I can't preview at all.
Maybe something is total wrong with my approach - I don't know.
And this should also work when later on the 2 apps are deployed.

What is the version of the used @ui5/cli in the project?

version is 4.0.11

As of December 2024, there is no built-in option to build or serve multiple application projects. We would like to introduce a new type "component" that would probably fit your needs here. This is envisioned to be introduced next year.
However, for the time being you might try the UI5 community middleware ui5-middleware-ui5 which is a workaround for this limitation.

here a sample repo where i used a local component in a ui5 app.
https://github.com/marianfoo/ui5con24-dev-env/tree/main/packages
